# How to export a formula from a SAS model

Tags: statistics, sas

I have a generalized Linear mixed model in SAS based on past data but I don't know how to export it to a pure mathematical formula that could be used to generates probabilities varying different inputs.

For example, I want to be able to input a values to different parameters and get a probability for that instance. Is there an easy way to export the mathematical model from SAS?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using `proc glimmix` for your model. You can use the `ODS output` tables to get the coef of your model in a table that you can implement internally using `proc score` our externally (export to excel?).

```
  ods output coef=coef;
   proc glimmix data=HessianFly;
      class block entry;
      model y/n = block entry / e;
   run;
```

ODS output table are available depending upon which options you have selected for your model.

Have a look at this [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glimmix_a0000001475.htm) - all available options for ods outputs

Hope it helps

Comment: You may want the `ParameterEstimates` table as well.